# Why does Array's pop method not have an exclamation mark?

Tags: ruby

I thought that by convention, only methods with an exclamation mark altered the object.

```
> array = [1, 2, 3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> array.pop
 => 3 
> array
 => [1, 2]
```

**Why isn't `Array`'s `pop` method called `pop!`?**

Comment: I'm with Mauricio--it's just not surprising; you're popping. That the structure is updated is implicit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not quite correct.

From [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

*The names of potentially "dangerous" methods (i.e. methods that modify self or the arguments, exit! (doesn't run the finalizers like exit does), etc.) should end with an exclamation mark if there exists a **safe version of that dangerous method**.*

And the name of pop method says exactly what it is doing so there's no need to sign it with exclamation mark.

Answer (score 2):

"The second convention is that any method whose name ends with an exclamation mark should be used with caution.(...) Often, methods that end with an exclamation mark are *mutators*, which alter the internal state of an object. But this is not always the case; there are many mutators that do not end with an exclamation mark , and a numbere of nonmutators that do. Mutating methods (such as `Array.fill`) that do not have a nonmutating variant do not typically have an exclamation point (sic)."

(The Ruby Programming Language, Flanagan &Matsumoto, page 180)

The book continues with the example `exit` versus `exit!` (both nonmutating; `exit!` skipping all at_exit hooks.)

Answer (score 1):

This convention is still valid, but `pop` is a well known method from all stack implementations, if you `pop` something from a stack you are effectively removing it.

That's just common knowledge in data structures, the ruby guys just missed adding the `!` sign to it.

Comment: No, there is no such convention. (The quoted Matsumoto in my answer is the language designer).

Comment: Try reading the text you quoted yourself @steenslag, you might find something on it's very first line.